# How to check every character in string?

Tags: c++, string, loops

The program will ask user to input strand which has to be composed of only ABCD and if the input contains letter other than ABCD it must show error, otherwise it should output "ok!"

```
string strand1;
again:
cout << "Enter String 1:\n";
cin >> strand1;
for (int i = 0; i <= strand1.length(); i++)
{
    if (strand1.at(i) != 'A'&&strand1.at(i) != 'B'&&strand1.at(i) != 'C'&&strand1.at(i) != 'D')
    {

        cout << "Invalid Input";
        system("cls");
        goto again;

    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
cout << "ok";
_getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: You're incrementing i twice.

Comment: ...... don't use goto in a loop; just don't.  That said I don't think you've thought your solution all the way through.  As you design your code try to code it like you'd handle it on paper.  Lastly, learn your loops and how to manipulate them to avoid having to use GOTO.  Goto is the unholy spawn of satan in 99.99% of cases.  In the other cases it is a necessary evil to speed your program up and cannot be avoided.  It is still quite evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but after examining your code I believe the problem is that for your loop condition you are using `i <= strand1.length` when you should be using `i < strand1.length`.
The loop condition you are using will check an index out of bounds of the string. In addition, you should not be incrementing i in the else statement as that is already done in the for statement. In the future, please clearly state your question along with any error codes you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the necessary checks to a function -- `isValidInput`.
2. Use hand coded logic to check whether the input is valid or use the standard library function `std::find_if` to do the same.
3. Use the function in a `while` loop in the `main` function.

```
bool isNotABCD(char c)
{
    return !((c == 'A') || (c == 'B') || (c == 'C') || (c == 'D'));
}

bool isValidInput(std::string const& str)
{
   return (std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isNotABCD) == str.end());
}

int main()
{
   string strand1;

   cout << "Enter String 1:\n";
   while ( cin >> strand1 && !isValidInput(strand1) )
   {
      cout << "Invalid Input";
      system("cls");
      cout << "Enter String 1:\n";
   }
   cout << "ok";
}
```

**Update**

You can also use a simpler version of `isValidInput()`, Thanks to @Blastfurnace for the suggestion.

```
bool isABCD(char c)
{
    return (c == 'A') || (c == 'B') || (c == 'C') || (c == 'D');
}

bool isValidInput(std::string const& str)
{
   return (std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isABCD));
}
```

**Update 2**

You can also use a still simpler version of `isValidInput()`, Thanks to @JorenHeit for the suggestion.

```
bool isValidInput(std::string const& str)
{
   return (std::find_first_not_of("ABCD") == std::string::npos);
}
```

Comment: Since you have a predicate, I think it might be simpler to use one of [`std::all_of`, `std::any_of`, `std::none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) instead of find_if.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, definitely better. Thanks.

Comment: @RSahu Or.... you could use `return str.find_first_of("ABCD") == std::string::npos;` I think that's more on the level of the OP as it avoids algorithms and iterators. Also, shouldn't it be a const ref?

Comment: @JorenHeit, That's better still.